# D3 table appending below each other instead of inside div

Tags: javascript, d3.js

guys! Back again with another D3 question!

I want to add two tables to my website, but the problem is, they're appearing below each other instead of inside their respective divs! The code I use is below (found it in JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/7WQjr/) and the only thing I change in them is the "#container" (which is a div) in the selectAll statement. I change is to container2 (another div) to create the other table.

```
function tabulate(data, columns) {
    var table = d3.select("#container").append("table"),
        thead = table.append("thead"),
        tbody = table.append("tbody");

    // append the header row
    thead.append("tr")
        .selectAll("th")
        .data(columns)
        .enter()
        .append("th")
            .text(function(column) { return column; });

    // create a row for each object in the data
    var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("tr");

    // create a cell in each row for each column
    var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
        .data(function(row) {
            return columns.map(function(column) {
                return {column: column, value: row[column]};
            });
        })
        .enter()
        .append("td")
            .text(function(d) { return d.value; });

    return table;
}

// create some people
var people = [
    {name: "Jill", age: 30},
    {name: "Bob", age: 32},
    {name: "George", age: 29},
    {name: "Sally", age: 31}
];

// render the table
var peopleTable = tabulate(people, ["name", "age"]);

// uppercase the column headers
peopleTable.selectAll("thead th")
    .text(function(column) {
        return column.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + column.substr(1);
    });

// sort by age
peopleTable.selectAll("tbody tr")
    .sort(function(a, b) {
        return d3.descending(a.age, b.age);
    });
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You need to change the selector for the container element in your function to append the second table to a different `div`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you pass the containers ID as a parameter? Something like this:

```
function tabulate(container, data, columns) {
  var table = d3.select('#' + container).append("table")
```

So you can call that function like this:

```
var peopleOrderedTable = tabulate('container1' , people, ["name", "age"]);
var peopleTable = tabulate('container2' , people, ["name", "age"]);
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you, Alex!